# setxkbmap in awesome 4 introduces 1min lag

Tags: keyboard-layout, awesome-wm

I frequently change my keyboard layout via `setxkbmap`.  Recently, this introduces a huge lag, where `awesome` is not responsive.  This happened after my switch to `v4.0` (I am not sure whether the upgrade is responsible, though...).

In my `.xerrors` I see a lot of entries

```
W: awesome: event_handle_mappingnotify:930: Unexpected MappingNotify of type 0
W: awesome: event_handle_mappingnotify:930: Unexpected MappingNotify of type 1
...
W: awesome: event_handle_mappingnotify:930: Unexpected MappingNotify of type 0
```

ended by

```
W: awesome: a_glib_poll:389: Last main loop iteration took 84.941757 seconds! Increasing limit for this warning to that value.
/usr/share/awesome/lib/beautiful/xresources.lua:84: W: Failed to get xrdb value 'Xft.dpi'
```

I am not sure whether this last entry is related, though.

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Comment: Which arguments exactly are you giving to setxkbmap? I would like to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Excuse the long silence.  And the faulty questions.  This is indeed the bug mentioned in the answer by Emmanuel Lepage Vallee.  I had unintentionally switched from setxkbdmap to xmodmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. See this GitHub issue

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1494

Comment: Thanks!  Right on spot.  I had unintentionally switched from setxkbdmap to xmodmap, so this bug directly applies.